# using devtmpfs for /dev

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, devices

I have noticed the following option in the kernel: CONFIG_DEVTMPFS

```
Device Drivers -> Generic Driver Options -> Maintain devtmpfs to mount at /dev
```

And I see that it is enabled by default in the Debian distribution kernel `3.2.0-4-amd64`

I am trying to understand what difference this option brings. Without this option, `/dev` is mounted as `tmpfs` , with this option, it is mounted as `devtmpfs`. Other than that, I don't see any difference.

The `help` did not clarify it for me either:

> This creates a tmpfs/ramfs filesystem instance early at bootup. In this filesystem, the kernel driver core maintains device nodes with their default names and permissions for all registered devices with an assigned major/minor number.
>
> It provides a fully functional /dev directory, where usually udev runs on top, managing permissions and adding meaningful symlinks.
>
> In very limited environments, it may provide a sufficient functional /dev without any further help. It also allows simple rescue systems, and reliably handles dynamic major/minor numbers.

Could somebody please explain the difference between using `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS` vs the standard `/dev`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`devtmpfs`](http://lwn.net/Articles/330985/) is a file system with automated device nodes populated by the kernel. This means you don't have to have udev running nor to create a static `/dev` layout with additional, unneeded and not present device nodes. Instead the kernel populates the appropriate information based on the known devices.

On the other hand the standard `/dev` handling requires either `udev`, an additional daemon running or to statically create device nodes on `/dev`.

Comment: Does it really mean, I don't need udev? The help says `It provides a fully functional /dev directory, where usually udev runs on top, managing permissions and adding meaningful symlinks`. If kernel populates `/dev`, what is there left to do for `udev` ?

Comment: In most circumstances you need `udev`. Directly from your quote, udev handles `managing permissions and adding meaningful symlinks` as well as running external scripts, notifying desktop environments etc.

Comment: So does that mean it's better to use devtmpfs instead of tmpfs for `/dev`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai yes, but your distribution should take care of that anyway