# Why do directories created under /dev disappear after reboot?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, devices

I'm new to Linux. When I try to create a directory in the `/dev` folder it's happening smoothly but after reboot all the created folders have disappeared.

I tried to create a folder in another folder, like `/etc`. There, created folders do *not* disappear. I tried it as a normal user and as a root user but the same thing happens.

How to create a directory under `/dev` that stays there permanently?

Comment: "Everywhere directories are not disappearing." /proc and /sys work just like /dev (aren't real physical storage), it's just that they won't let you create any directories there.

Comment: @val: To be fair, back in the old days, `/dev` was usually just a directory that was part of the root filesystem, and what the OP was doing would just work.  Any (Unix) filesystem can contain block-device or char-device file types, just like named pipes or symlinks or other non-regular file types.  `/dev` is not as special as `/proc` and `/sys` are: you can create your own dirs in it.  On some systems, it's just a normal `tmpfs` mount that user-space software (`udev`) uses `mknod` to populate with device files.  (`devtmpfs` lets the kernel create device nodes there for you, without udev)

Comment: Anyway, `mount` or `df /dev` will clearly show that `/dev` is a special mount, so your overall point is certainly fair.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, you can create files and/or directories under `/dev/`. But you can't expect them to still be there after a reboot.

Here is why: the `dev` filesystem is responsible for device access. It's not a block filesystem (with underlying "real" storage) but a memory-based filesystem. As it exists only in RAM everything under `/dev/` is erased upon shutdown and recreated on boot.

The population of `/dev/` can be done in three ways:

- statically (nowadays very uncommon)
- on the userspace level by using the `udev` software
- on the the kernel level using `devtmpfs`.

Here are some links to excellent posts detailing this:

- explanation of the `dev` filesystem: [Understanding /dev and its subdirs and files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18239/understanding-dev-and-its-subdirs-and-files)
- explanation of `devtmpfs`: [using devtmpfs for /dev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77933/using-devtmpfs-for-dev)
- how `dev` files are created: [How are "/dev" Linux files created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241173/how-are-dev-linux-files-created)

Comment: Shorter version: `/dev` is special; if you don't know *how* to create persistent files and directories in there, you *really shouldn't be doing so to begin with*.

Comment: On modern Linux systems the kernel manages `/dev` because it's mounted as [devtmpfs](/a/77936/211239).

Comment: @iBug yes, that's a very good addition, I edited my answer to properly reflect that

Comment: On some older Unix (not Linux) systems, `/dev` was a real directory (not tmpfs), but it's contents was re-generated on each reboot by a special script/tool run on boot that was detecting hardware and fill in `/dev` appropriately.